# Packery - how to change layout mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, packery

I'd like to use this plugin: http://packery.metafizzy.co/ with layout mode: meticulous as described on the frontpage. I went through every page of documentation and cannot find how to set it to meticulous instead of masonry layout which is default!

[image]

```
var $container = $('#grid_index');
// initialize
$container.packery({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  gutter: 0
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer my question directly, layout mode "meticulous" is triggered automatically by setting: `columnWidth` and `rowHeight` in options.

Like this:

```
var $container = $('#grid_index');
var pckry = $container.data('packery');
// initialize
$container.packery({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  gutter: 0,
  "columnWidth": 250,
  "rowHeight": 250
});
```